# How to get permission names and members from list permissions in powershell?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, list, powershell, permissions

In Sharepoint, I have a list with custom permissions:

I want to create a powershell script that can loop through the permissions, and get two things, 1 is the permission name, and the other is the name, weather it is a person or group.

I have this:

```
$lists = $spWeb.Lists | Where-Object {$_.Title.StartsWith('custom_')}
$listCount = $lists.Count


write-host ("Found {0} lists..." -f $listCount)
foreach ($list in $lists) {
    $collRoleDefinitions = $list.RoleDefinitions;
    $collRoleAssignments = $list.RoleAssignments;

    #write-host $collRoleDefinitions
    $assignments = $collRoleAssignments


    foreach($role in $assignments) {
       write-host $role
    }
}
```

but I don't know how to get the permission name and user account.  For the user account I think this might work

```
$role.Member;
```

but unsure about the permission name. Basically I want to get things like "Contribute" or "Full Control".

Does anyone know?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can try following script:

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell
$WebUrl = Read-Host 'Please input URL address of target web'
$Web = Get-SPWeb $WebUrl
$ListName = Read-Host 'Please input list name'
$List = $web.Lists[$ListName]

$Unique = $List.hasuniqueroleassignments 

if (($List.permissions -ne $null) -and ($Unique -eq "True")) 
{
  Write-Output "---------------------"
  Write-Output "List permission is: "
  $List.permissions | fl member, basepermissions 
}
elseif ($Unique -ne "True") { 
  Write-Output "Inherits permissions from $Web" 
} 

Write-Host "----------------------" 

$web.dispose()

pause
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried the following code to get the members and permissions level name for a specific list based on `RoleAssignments` and `Member` as the following

```
$web = Get-SPWeb http://epm/workflow
$list = $web.Lists["listview"]
$list.RoleAssignments | Format-List member, roledefinitionbindings
```

**[Output]**

[image]

Also, check how to get the members and permissions details based on `BasePermissions` and `Member` as the following

```
$web = Get-SPWeb http://epm/workflow
$list = $web.Lists["listview"]
$list.permissions | Format-list member, basepermissions
```

**[OutPut]**

[image]